# Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to ELK and recently installed ELK on Windows Server 2008 and on Windows 7 machine.

But on both the places if I open Kibana I get the message: "Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?"

My logstash confiuration file looks like

```
 input { 
     file {
  type => "AppLog"
  path => "D:/LogFiles"
  }
  }

filter {
  mutate {
  add_field => [ "hostip", "%{host}" ]
     }
  dns {
  reverse => [ "host" ]
   action => replace
      }
       }

  output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
   protocol => "http"
    codec => rubydebug
       }
    }
```

This URL returns **"{"error":"IndexMissingException[[logstash-*] missing]","status":404}"***
http://localhost:5601/elasticsearch/logstash-/_mapping/field/*?ignore_unavailable=false&allow_no_indices=false&include_defaults=true

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Do you have any indices in ES?

Comment: No, I can only see .kibana folder. Could you please guide me on how to add those indices? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't say what version of ES/Kibana/Logsatsh you're using, but I would suggest that you start with checking your logs for each tier and seeing if there's errors. Also, I don't think you want your codec to be `rubydebug` when using ES. I suspect that will cause issues, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Also, you don't create those indices, Logstash does.

Comment: @GregL:  I am using following versions elasticsearch-1.6.0, kibana-4.0.3-windows and logstash-1.5.0. And also I tried codec without `rubydebug`.

I am only checking on a single system. I just installed on the server trying to figure out on how to get start with that as I struck with this error.
Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: Like I said, check your logs and update your question with any errors you find. [This](https://community.ulyaoth.net/threads/how-to-install-logstash-on-a-windows-server-with-kibana-in-iis.17/) how-to is for Windows 2012 and older versions of ES, Kibana and Logstash, but the principles should still be the same. Maybe see if that can help you out as well.